# Pulling images from folder, 403 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting a 403 forbidden error on this script. After talking on the phone with my service provider they said that my code is wrong and that I'm mapping it wrong. But I know I'm not, because if I was mapping it wrong I would get a 404 error and not a 403 error. Is this correct? Basically I'm pulling images from a folder and putting them into a slideshow. But Javascript gets a 403 error. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dir = "Ads/";
  var fileextension = ".jpg";
  $.ajax({
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
      $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
        var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
        var newimage = document.createElement('li');
        newimage.innerHTML = ('<img src="'+dir+filename+'" width="100%" height="100%" />');
        document.getElementById("localAds").appendchild(newimage);
      });
    }
  });
});
$(function () {
  var change_img_time     = 5000; 
  var transition_speed    = 100;
  var simple_slideshow    = $("#localAds"),
  listItems           = simple_slideshow.children('li'),
  listLen             = listItems.length,
  i                   = 0,
  changeList = function () {
    listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(transition_speed, function () {
      i += 1;
      if (i === listLen) {
        i = 0;
      }
      listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(transition_speed);
    });
  };
  listItems.not(':first').hide();
  setInterval(changeList, change_img_time);
});
```

Edit:

HTML:

```
<ul id="localAds" class="crop"></ul>
```

CSS:

```
.crop {
  width: 353px;
  height: 206px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.crop img {
  width: 353px;
  height: 206px;
}
```

The page looks like business card sized images running through a slideshow.

Comment: tried to add an / in front of your dirname?

Comment: tried /, tried ../

Comment: What does the finished image url look like?

Comment: edited original post to reflect what the page should look like

Comment: Well, it's telling you 403 Forbidden, so that probably means your web server can't get to the image. Check permissions.

Comment: can you open that directory in a browser? Sounds like server is not set up to display directory indexes

Comment: After arguing again with the provider he admitted that the folder was not browsable. Go figure. thank you all for your time.